# confitional focus on textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two checkboxes like this:

```
<input id="isGenericPassword" name="isGenericPassword"
       onclick="IsGenericOrUnique(this.id);" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="isGenericPassword" type="hidden" value="false" />
<input checked="checked" id="isUniquePassword" name="isUniquePassword"
       onclick="IsGenericOrUnique(this.id);" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="isUniquePassword" type="hidden" value="false" />
<input id="UniquePassword" name="UniquePassword" style="display:none"
       type="text" value="" />
```

in document.ready, I have

```
 $('#isUniquePassword').is(':checked')
     ? $("#UniquePassword").show()
     : $("#UniquePassword").hide();
```

so that related textbox is visible if checkbox is checked.

I am hiding the textbox UniquePassword on click of isUniquePassword checkbox

```
$("#isUniquePassword").click(function () {
    $("#UniquePassword").toggle(this.checked);
    if ($("#isUniquePassword").is(':checked')) {
        // unique password gets focus only if related checkbox is checked
        $("#UniquePassword").focus();
    }
});
```

and show dialogue when user tries to go away without typing anything

```
 $("#UniquePassword").blur(function () {
     if ($("#isUniquePassword").is(':checked') &&
         $("#UniquePassword").val() == '')
     {
         $("#dialog-RecipientEmail-error").dialog("open");                        
     }
 });
```

and on Ok button click of that dialogue, setting focus again to that textbox so that value is entered

```
  $("#dialog-RecipientEmail-error").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      resizeable: false,
      width: 300,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
          "OK": function () {
              $(this).dialog("close");
              $("#UniquePassword").focus();
          }
      }
  });
```

No I want that if isGenericPassword is checked or isUniquePassword is unchecked then I should get that error dialogue

Comment: What's the question/problem?

Comment: Could you put your problem in JSFiddle ? it's easier and faster to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

$("#UniquePassword").focus();  will not focus the field rather it will trigger the actions which are bound with focus event. To focus a field, you need to get the handle of the HTML element

`$("#UniquePassword").get(0).focus();`

That should work.

Comment: I want that UniquePassword gets focus only if isUniquePassword is checked if user unchecks it or tries to check isgenericPassword, then blur event doesnt fire.

Comment: @Mahbub: According to [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) the call to `.focus()` is equivalent to `.trigger("focus")` which means that focus is triggered on the HTML element. Additionally documentation also says: *To run an element's focus event handlers **without setting focus to the element**, use `.triggerHandler("focus")` instead of `.focus()`.*

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed that update in Doc. It used be like that earlier like i described if you had been following jQuery for longer :)